# SQL Server aggregation the latest 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Id   Visitors Date
------------------------------
1     100     '2017-01-01'
2     200     '2017-01-02'
3     150     '2017-01-03'
```

I want a query to provide the average of a range of records for the last 12 months.

For one record I know that it would be like :

```
select avg(Visitors), Date 
from Visitors_table 
where Date between '2018-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
```

However, I need to do that for a range of dates and multiple records.

I know that `Union` will solve it, but if the range is one year for example It is not optimized to use 365 union

Comment: The column labeled "Visitors" here appears to be the count of visitors on a specific date. Is the average that you are looking for the average number of visitors per day during the last 12 months? Thanks

Comment: Your `between` filters out all records, so it is really hard to understand what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the dates from 1 year ago to current date:

```
SELECT 
  Date,
  AVG(Visitors) AS avgvisitors, 
FROM Visitors_table 
WHERE Date > dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date;
```

Since you need to group by date.

Comment: You forgot group by date
Thanks :)

Comment: GROUP BY Date is redundant in this case because it counts all the rows unless there are multiple rows with the same Date.

Comment: It need group by
You can try it
I need the average for each day , not only for one

Comment: See my edited answer. Although from your sample data I did not see multiple rows for the same date.

Comment: It should be continues
Real table has many records from 2010 till  now
But the above table is just a sample

Comment: So is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes sure
Thanks